# What is the reason behind the following

Tags: measure-theory

We define inner measure of a set Supremum of the lengths of $closed$ sets contained in the set while as we define outer measure as Infimum of the lengths of $open$ sets containing the set. 
What is the reason behind this.

Well I saw a result that for every set $A$ and and every $\epsilon >0$ we can always find an open set $O$ such that $m^*(O)\leq m^*(A)+\epsilon$

Well this accounts some that why we take open sets that cover the given set...

why we take closed for inner measure and not open sets.

Comment: Otherwise inner will always be zero and outer - infinity. Pretty boring, right?

Comment: @rtybase Sir I think it is immaterial wether we cover a set $A$ by open sets or closed sets containg $A$,the infimum of the lengths will never be zero provided the length of $A$ is not zero.

Am I right sir?

And sir it is not boring it deserves your attention...

Comment: You misunderstood the boring part :) ... The question is "what is the reason". The concept is similar to circumscribing and inscribing a circle by polygons. If you don't take the infimum (for circumscribing) or supremum (for inscribing), the whole construction will never "approach" the "measure" of A. In particular it may be constants like zero or infinity, and this (!!!) is boring.

Comment: But now, after you edited your question, I see what are you after ...

Answer (score 2):

One element of response :

Take the set $\mathbf R \backslash \mathbf Q$, since $\mathbf Q$ is countable you know that, in a coherent measure theory, $\mathbf R \backslash \mathbf Q$ should be of full measure.

Now if we define the inner measure with the sup of open set then the inner measure of $\mathbf R \backslash \mathbf Q$ would be $0$.

The same works with outer measure defined with closed set : in this case the set $\mathbf Q$ would be of full outer measure. And note that, in that way, the outer measure wouldn't be an outer measure since it wouldn't be sub sigma additive.